# Checking if Territory has Users

Tags: apex, code, user-record, null, territory

Is there a way to check if a territory has a user assigned? I tried using UserTerritory2Associations to query by a TerritoryId and log 'doesnt exist' or 'exist' if the result is null or not. But it is only logging when the result isn't null so it seems like  New to Salesforce so I hope that makes sense!

Below is a snippet where I was trying to see if it is possible for a query to return null...

```
UserTerritory2AssociationsSelector userAssInst = new UserTerritory2AssociationsSelector();
Set<Id> terrIds = new Set<Id>();
terrIds.add('0MIP0000000HK3JOAW'); //has user assigned
terrIds.add('0MIP0000000HK3OOAW'); //no user assigned

System.debug('start');

for( UserTerritory2Association user : 
    (List<UserTerritory2Association>) userAssInst.selectUserTerrByTerrId(terrIds)
   ){
      System.debug(user.UserId == null ? 'doesnt exist' : 'exist'); 
   }

System.debug('end');
```

```
public List<UserTerritory2Association> selectUserTerrByTerrId(Set<Id> terrIds) {
        fflib_QueryFactory query = newQueryFactory();
        selectFields(
            query,
            new List<String>{
                'Territory2Id',                
                'Territory2.Territory2Type.DeveloperName',
                'UserId'
            }
        );   
        query.setCondition('Territory2Id IN: terrIds');
        return (List<UserTerritory2Association>) Database.query(query.toSOQL());
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to run a for loop, just check if the query result size is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

As your query is returning the list of `UserTerritory2Association` you can easily convert it into `Map<id, UserTerritory2Association>`, and then on that map, you can run a check if the Id is present or not in the keySet.

```
UserTerritory2AssociationsSelector userAssInst = new UserTerritory2AssociationsSelector();
Set<Id> terrIds = new Set<Id>();
terrIds.add('0MIP0000000HK3JOAW');
terrIds.add('0MIP0000000HK3OOAW'); 
 
// collect user ids from the result.
Set<Id> resultIds = new Set<Id>();
for(UserTerritory2Association userTerr: usersPresent){
    resultIds.add(userTerr.Territory2Id);
}

resultIds.containsKey('0MIP0000000HK3JOAW');
```

If you want to check all records at once and run the "all or none" check then you can use the following code.

```
resultIds.containsAll(terrIds); // this will give you a boolean value: true or false
```

Also, you can run a for loop to check if you want to check each record one by one.

```
for(Id terrId: terrIds){
    usersPresent.containsKey(terrId); // this will give you a boolean value: true or false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The junction record `UserTerritory2Association`won't exist if the territory has no users assigned.

You could do the following (straight SOQL, I'll leave it to you to adapt to fflib Selector pattern)

```
Territory2 territoriesWithAssignments = 
   [SELECT Id, Name (SELECT Id FROM UserTerritory2Associations
                  LIMIT 1)  /* only need 1 to prove an association */
    FROM Territory2
    WHERE Id IN: terrIds
   ];
for (Territory2 t: territoriesWithAssignments ) {
   if (t.UserTerritory2Associations.isEmpty()) {System.debug('No assignments for ' + t.Name);}
   else { System.debug('1+ assignments for ' + t.Name);
}
```